# Join two datasets by two matching columns in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse

**Objective**

I have two datasets:   df1  and df2

```
df1


Date           Name      Duration

1/2/2020       Tanisha   50
1/3/2020       Lisa      10
1/5/2020       Lisa      10



df2


Date           Name      Duration

1/2/2020       Tanisha   80
1/3/2020       Lisa      50
1/5/2020       Tom       10
```

**Desired output:**

```
  Date           Name      Duration        Date           Name       Duration

  1/2/2020       Tanisha   50              1/2/2020       Tanisha     80  
  1/3/2020       Lisa      10              1/3/2020       Lisa        50
```

I wish to match the contents in the name column with df1 and df2 as well as the Date column

**Dput for df1 and df2:**

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1/2/2020", "1/3/2020", 
 "1/5/2020"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L
  ), .Label = c("Lisa", "Tanisha"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(50L, 
 10L, 10L), X = c(NA, NA, NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA), X.2 = c(NA, 
 NA, NA), X.3 = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))



structure(list(Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1/2/2020", "1/3/2020", 
"1/5/2020"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L
), .Label = c("lisa", "tanisha", "tom"), class = "factor"), Duration2 = c(80L, 
50L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**What I have tried:**

horizontal merge

```
 merge(df1, df2, all.x=True)
```

I am unsure how to match the Name AND Date contents

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple merge but your `Name` columns are not uniform. Convert them to similar form (either upper, lower or title case) and then merge. Also no need to have duplicate columns for `Date` and `Name` since they carry the exact same information.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(Name = tolower(Name)) %>% inner_join(df2, by = c('Date', 'Name'))
```

Or in base R :

```
merge(transform(df1, Name = tolower(Name)), df2, by = c('Date', 'Name'))


#      Date    Name Duration Duration2
#1 1/2/2020 tanisha       50        80
#2 1/3/2020    lisa       10        50
```

Comment: Hello @ronak, the columns in my real dataset are both uppercase and match. Can I just remove the 'to lower?    df1 %>% mutate(Name = (Name)) %>% inner_join(df2, by = c('Date', 'Name'))   ??

Comment: In that case you don't need `mutate`, do `inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('Date', 'Name'))`